# ¿Cómo funciona maven?

Tags: java, maven

Estoy empezando a leer sobre spring framework, donde en el curso usan maven y ya hay cosas que no entiendo, las cuales algunas no tienen que ver con spring o maven, sino más con java.

Bueno, lo primero es ¿maven, al agregar una dependencia al archivo pom.xml, me descarga automáticamente la librería (las clases) a mi proyecto?

La segunda pregunta viene con esta imagen:

[image: Proyecto]

¿Por qué al hacer un proyecto con Spring o maven, se me agregan tantas carpetas que no tienen ningún contenido? (Ej: src-target)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La respuesta a la primera pregunta es sí, maven se encarga de descargar las librerías que declaras como dependencia para tu proyecto solo si estas librerías se encuentran en alguno de los [repositorios centrales de maven (ver sección Approved Repository Hosting)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html). Pero maven hace mucho más que esto. Maven también te permite descargar las fuentes y la documentación de esos proyectos (si es que están disponibles).  Asimismo, Maven también descargará las dependencias de las librerías que indicas como dependencia. Por ejemplo, Spring Core 4.2.5 depende de la librería commons-codec versión 1.10 (tal como se muestra [en su archivo pom.xml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.pom)), si Maven detecta que no tienes dicha librería instalada localmente, entonces la descargará por ti.

Detallando un poco, cuando declaras una dependencia en Maven, realizará lo siguiente:

- Busca si la librería se encuentra en tu repositorio local de maven, usualmente ubicado en `<carpeta de usuario>/.m2`. En Windows sería `C:\Users\<tu usuario>\.m2`. En Mac sería `/Users/<tu usuario>/.m2`, y así.
- En caso de no estar allí, descargará la librería de un repositorio central.

Cabe resaltar que Maven utilizará las librerías descargadas para compilar tu proyecto. Esto **NO significa** que tu artefacto final contendrá las dependencias embebidas en él. Esto depende del tipo de proyecto y de algunas configuraciones adicionales que puedes realizar en Maven. Por ejemplo, si tu proyecto es de tipo jar, Maven por defecto no agregará ninguna dependencia en el jar generado. Sin embargo, si tu proyecto es de tipo war, Maven por defecto agregará las dependencias dentro de la carpeta WEB-INF/lib (estándar de aplicaciones web Java).

---

La segunda pregunta está respondida y bien detallada en [Introducción al Diseño Estándar de Directorios de Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) (enlace en inglés). De todas formas, aquí brindo un detalle para las carpetas que tienes en tu proyecto según la imagen que has mostrado:

- src: Carpeta para todas las fuentes y recursos utilizados en el proyecto

  - main: Fuentes y recursos principales del proyecto. Por defecto, los elementos ubicados en esta carpeta se agregarán al artefacto generado (jar, war, etc)
  - java: Fuentes del proyecto. Por defecto, en el artefacto generado se agregan los compilados de los archivos Java (.java) ubicados aquí, Cualquier otro tipo de archivo (p.e. xml) se ignorarán. Si hay algún error de compilación, el artefacto no se generará.
  - resources: Recursos del proyecto. Aquí residen los archivos de configuración y otros recursos adicionales a utilizar en el proyecto. Por ejemplo: imágenes (jgp, pgn), archivos de configuración (properties, xml, json), plantillas (xlsx, docx, pdf), entre otros. Por defecto, todos los archivos se almacenan directamente en el artefacto generado.
  - test: Fuentes y recursos utilizados durante la fase de pruebas del proyecto. Por defecto, Maven NO agregará estos archivos en el artefacto generado.
  - java: Fuentes de pruebas del proyecto. Estas fuentes serán compiladas junto con las fuentes ubicadas en src/main/java. Estos compilados no se agregan en el artefacto generado. Sin embargo, si existe un error de compilación el artefacto no se generará. Para evitar esto, puedes indicar en tu IDE que no se utilice la fase de pruebas o desde línea de comandos utilizar `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true`.
- target: Contiene todos los elementos generados tras ejecutar Maven (mvn) sobre el proyecto. Esto incluye: archivos generados en tiempo de compilación, compilados, artefacto final generado (jar, war, etc)

---

Adicional, Maven por defecto hará que tu proyecto utilice Java 5 (tal como se muestra en la imagen, tu proyecto utiliza Java 5 o J2SE 1.5). Para evitar ello y utilizar tu versión favorita de Java (6, 7, 8, 9?) debes agregar un plugin bajo la sección build en tu archivo pom.xml:

```xml
<properties>
    <!-- En mi caso, declaro utilizar Java 8 en el proyecto -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Ten en cuenta que `<build>` y `<dependencies>` son dos secciones separadas.

Answer (score 3):

> primero es si maven al agregar una dependencia al archivo pom.xml, me
>   descarga automáticamente la librería(las clases) a mi proyecto?

Si, exactamente es lo que realiza.

> con Spring o maven, se me agregan tantas carpetas que no tienen ningún
>   contenido?(Ej: src-target)

El directorio `/target` es donde se crean los archivos cuando realizas el build!

Aquí hay una lista de directorios creados por Maven, donde se especifica para que sirven (inglés) :

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html